# How to listen to messages from specific users socket.io node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am developing a node js social media application and I am using the express framework and MongoDB as a database and socket.io for WebSockets based connections.

in the application, a user can send a friend request to another user to be friends and also a user can create a post.

I want to emit the new post added event to only the users whom are friends with the post adder.

something like:

```js
io.on('postAdded' , (data) => {
   io.to(friendsOnly).emit('posts', data);   
 });
```

is it possible to achieve that using socket.io and express based node js server?

Thanks,

Comment: `io.on('postAdd', ...)` is not correct.  It would have to be `socket.on('postAdd', ..)` inside an `io.connection(socket => { ... })`.  This general structure could work if `friendsOnly` was a socket.io room of only the right friends for the socket.  Otherwise, you will have to iterate the friends of that socket's user and `.emit()` to each of them.

Comment: do you mean to create a room called friends only for each user and then emit to this room?

Comment: Well, that's how `io.to()` works.  It relies on rooms and that's what you were asking about.  But, it really depends upon how you have the friends stored.  If you have a data structure that has the friends in it, then just iterate that and call `.emit()` on each friend's socket.  We can't really help much here without understanding how you have the friends stored and how you associate them with the friend's socket.